# ESP-IDF missing driver using an ESP-32

Tags: c, driver, esp32, esp-idf

I'm trying to build a project with an ESP-32 but when i'm trying to build the project it came with this error

> " fatal error: driver/i2c.h: No such file or directory 21 | #include
> "driver/i2c.h" "

I'm using a tutorial to flash my esp-32 : https://github.com/mjuhanne/fyrtur-esp in the "sdk" part the author show how to build it and my error came when i tried to do "idf.py app"

anybody has an idea ?
thanks :)

I search on internet to install a librairy or anything else but i don't find it, I'm new with esp-32

Answer (score 0):

I have similar include problems when I was using ESP-IDF v.5 with some older projects, some of the modules were changed. Moreover, the drivers used by the project are likely to be older as well.

Possible solutions:

I believe it would help to try downgrading the ESP-IDF you're using to the version used in the project, **v.4.4.3** should be alright.

I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you veryyyy much !
This helped me a lot, it compiled much better
I'm not familiar with this env so i will ask you another question sorry to bother you,

I have this error when compiling
fatal error: mqtt_config.h: No such file or directory #include "mqtt_config.h"

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm out of ideas here. Try it with multiple versions maybe lower, it might help. I'm not sure if there is any significant difference but you wanna try idf.py build.